Ancestry & FTM- unknown names
I know there are differing opinions on the best way to enter unknown surnames and forenames, but my question pertains to Ancestry specifically. Does anyone know what naming convention(s) for unknown names would allow their search algorithms to function properly? Is it different for surnames and forenames?

Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! I have edited your post to take out the request to source our information (because we're all supposed to be doing that!) and your thanks. If you are helped by someone's answer, you can say thanks by upvoting their answer. You can find out more about our site by reading the [help] and by asking questions in  our companion [meta] site.

Ancestry's Support article Entering names in your Ancestry® Family Tree discusses how to record variant first names and how to enter them in your tree.  Their advice for entering unknown surnames, if you don't want to leave the field blank, is to enter five underscores:

If you don't know someone's last name at birth, leave their last name
blank or enter five underscores: "_____." Leaving last name fields
blank or using five underscores to create a blank line helps you later
identify where further research is needed.

Crista Cowan says in her Barefoot Genealogy video Many Names, One Person: Data Entry Tips for All that Information | Ancestry that entering the five underscores does not interfere with Ancestry's search or hint algorithms.  She enters five underscores for unknown maiden names for women, and for forenames where she has a husband's surname and not his first name.
If you know neither the first or last names (e.g. "wife of John Smith), try entering five underscores for both names.  If Ancestry's online tree system doesn't give you an error message, you can be confident that the underscores won't interfere with searches or hints.

It should maybe be noted that for searching purposes, Ancestry.com appears to treat the 5 underscores the same as a blank field, i.e., you can't search for entries that have the 5 underscores (either in others' trees or your own), just as you can't search for entries using blank fields as a search criterion.
